# Organizing Android Gradle Project for Inherited Builds

Tags: gradle, android-studio, android-build, build.gradle

I have a set of apps which are basically white labels of one app. The basic app has a web backend. With `ant`, when I ran the `debug` build of a white label app, the library project was compiled as `debug` with `dev_server` parameters and when I compiled a `release` build, the `live_server` parameters were used. Other parameters (and resources) were overridden by the white label app and it all worked pretty well.

So basically, if I compiled a white label for app 1 and `debug` build, the app was compiled for `<dev_server>/1` as the basic service address and so on.

With `gradle`, I've tried different strategies but can't get it to work quite as conveniently without setting each parameter in each app's `build.gradle`. 
The basic problem seems to be that a library project with `gradle` always builds in `release` so I can really change backend parameters based on what build I'm using.

Any ideas how to set up the project structure to make it work that way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of library project, try going for the productFlavour concept as mentioned here http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Product-flavors

Comment: Indeed... have started using those since.